# HTML: How to open Anchor tag URL with comma?

Tags: html

Basic HTML anchor or URL redirect or form submit only.
I just want to submit the following url format but the problem is it have a comma in the URL, when I try the below method the comma is not included in the browser link that opened. How do I include the comma when user clicks the anchor or button? I'm using PHP, is there any function that can help me also?

https://myportal.cat-item.do?key=cat_item,46f69443db

My code:

```
<form method="get" 
action=" https://myportal.cat-item.do?key=cat_item,46f69443db ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Click Here </button>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a form, with `method="GET"`, the data in the form will be used to generate a new query string and this will replace any query string in the action.

Use a regular link:

```
<a href="https://myportal.cat-item.do?key=cat_item,46f69443db">Click Here</a>
```

Note that with your code, the *whole* query string will be replaced, not just the part after the comma. The comma is not a special character and, all else being equal, will not be removed.